# Merge 2 existing 2-way light switches

Tags: lighting

I have two separate lights, both are wired with two 2-way switches, four in total.  The box in the center contains one of each circuit.  I wanted to replace them with a 3-way switch to merge both lights and all the switches on the same circuit.  How would that look?  Or is there a way to bridge them?

Comment: What country is this in? (Wiring codes vary.) Can you upload pictures of the existing switch boxes?

Comment: in the US, there isn't anything called a "2-way" switch. A single switch controlling a load is called a "single pole" switch, a circuit with 2 different switches controlling a load is called a "3-way" circuit and both switches are called 3-way switches.

Comment: Pretty sure it'll need new wire.  An extra wire is needed for the loop.

Comment: where does the power come in?